# JOIN two tables (one needs concatenating)

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in a wordpress database.
One table is "users" and contains the columns:
ID, user_url, user_email

I need to join this to a second table "usermeta" which contains the columns:
user_ID, meta_key, meta_value but which needs to have the rows concatenated first.

```
user_id meta_key    meta_value
1       first_name  Joe
1       last_name   Smith
2       first_name  Jane
2       last_name   Doe
```

needs to become

```
user_id meta_key                meta_value
1       first_name,last_name    Joe,Smith
2       first_name,last_name    Jane,Doe
```

I have been able to join the tables using:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users
INNER JOIN usermeta ON usermeta.user_id = users.ID
GROUP BY usermeta.user_id");
```

However, when printing/echoing the results, "echo $row['meta_value'];" only returns the first row for a given ID.

If i don't group it, i end up with multiple rows for each user_id

I can make the concatenating work using:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(meta_value) AS Customer_Address
FROM usermeta
WHERE usermeta.meta_key='first_name' 
or usermeta.meta_key='last_name' 
or usermeta.meta_key='paupress_address_one_1' 
or usermeta.meta_key='paupress_address_city_1' 
or usermeta.meta_key='paupress_address_state_1' 
or usermeta.meta_key='paupress_address_postal_code_1'
or usermeta.meta_key='user_type'
or usermeta.meta_key='telephone'
or usermeta.meta_key='paupress_field_business'
GROUP BY user_id");
```

However, this solution doesn't give me access to the first table. I need a way to concatenate one table AND join it to the other based on user id and then be able to print the values for email, url and the concatenated "Customer_Address"

I have tried all sorts of combinations and subqueries but can't seem to make this work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to combine your first query and your second query.  Here is a condensed version:

```
SELECT u.user_id, 
     u.email,
     u.url,
     GROUP_CONCAT(meta_value) AS customer_address
FROM user u
     JOIN usermeta um ON u.user_id = um.user_id
WHERE um.meta_key IN ('first_name','last_name')
GROUP BY u.user_id
```

Comment: this worked perfectly! I spent 12 hours on this yesterday...thank you soooooo much!

Answer (score 0):

if you are using wordpress CMS, you should query follow wordpress tag:
Get all meta data for user:

```
$all_meta_for_user = get_user_meta( 1 );
print_r( $all_meta_for_user );
```

you can get first_name and last_name through $all_meta_for_user array

Or If you only get first_name and last_name, you can try this:

```
 echo $user_last = get_user_meta( 1, 'first_name', true );
 echo $user_last = get_user_meta( 1, 'last_name', true );
```

To get meta data for all user, you can used to loop and change user_id.